# RSpec: controller_specs for resource with relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I know this is a basic question but there's so much confusing, outdated & contradicting information out there...I've managed to scramble my brain... How best to access parent model from a child's controller spec...using FactoryGirl?

It may be *partially* related to using the value from parent model (user.name) in the (to_params) of the child. This is working fine for me. I'm just having a hard time testing it:

Pseudo models:

```
User
  :name - string - unique
  :email - string - unique
  has_many :ballots

Ballot
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items

  def to_param #
    "#{id} #{user.name}".parameterize
  end
```

factories.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :email do |n|
    "person#{n}@fake_mail.com"
  end

  sequence :name do |n|
    "Person#{n}"
  end

  factory :user do
    name "Joe Schmo"
    email
  end

  factory :sequenced_user, :parent => :user do
    name
    email
  end

  factory :ballot do
    sequenced_user
  end
```

ballots_controller_spec.rb:

```
describe BallotsController do

  def valid_attributes
    FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:ballot)
  end

  describe "GET show" do
    it "assigns the requested ballot as @ballot" do
      ballot = Ballot.create! valid_attributes
      get :show, {:id => ballot.to_param}, valid_session
      assigns(:ballot).should eq(ballot)
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

spec failure:

```
  1) BallotsController GET show assigns the requested ballot as @ballot
     Failure/Error: get :show, {:id => ballot.to_param}, valid_session
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/models/ballot.rb:5:in `to_param'
     # ./spec/controllers/ballots_controller_spec.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  ...
```

Problem, appears to be, that the running spec doesn't access to the `name` of the User that the ballot is associated with. But, the Ballot factory has an associated user in it!?! So, what's the correct way to generate this relationship using FactoryGirl?

Comment: can you post the line: `./app/models/ballot.rb:5` and surrounding context? (function `#to_param`)

Comment: It's up there. basically `Ballot` class consists of `belongs_to :user` and the `to_param` (which you can see above).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
factory :ballot do
  association :user, :factory => :sequenced_user
end
```

It seems like FactoryGirl was trying to make `ballot.sequenced_user`, when you want just `ballot.user`